# How to convert 2D ndarray to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have `ndarray` (`numpy array`) (name: `X`) with `shape`: (1000, 55)

I want to convert it to `pandas` `dataframe` with shape (1000, 2):

first `df` column = first X column

second `df` column = rest of X columns

I tried with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':X[:,0]})
df['series'] = pd.Series(X[:,1:-1])
```

but I'm getting errors (`Data must be 1-dimensional`)

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':X[:,0]})
df['series'] = X[:,1:].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it (with random data, of course):

```
data = np.random.rand(1000, 65)
pd.DataFrame({"a": data[:,0], "b": (list(x) for x in data[:,1:])})
```

The output is:

```
            a                                                  b
0    0.033109  [0.16260718783576944, 0.9285169675075658, 0.21...
1    0.875634  [0.40738562865096173, 0.6440679729423946, 0.68...
2    0.486732  [0.09350635426799858, 0.8287836094572563, 0.70...
3    0.081493  [0.7139459852434121, 0.666703381938375, 0.2319...
4    0.874734  [0.27530490806669217, 0.8500315566615584, 0.11...
..        ...                                                ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one-line solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame((X[:,0], X[:,1:]), index=['ID', 'series']).T
```